# Run code without ART/Dalvik involvement in Android

Tags: android, c++, linux

I have a couple of questions about the Android operating system's runtime environment.

1. Are Android libraries (e.g., OpenGL, SSL, etc.) compiled to bytecodes and executed by ART/Dalvik?
2. How does Android run cpp codes (pure cpp not hybrid java code with cpp calls)? Does it convert them to bytecodes and run them on ART/Dalvik or does it run them directly as user processes? If it runs them on ART/Dalvik, is there a way to manually bypass ART/Dalvik and run the code directly as a user process? If so, does this need root access?
3. What about Python codes?

Comment: C/C++ code, whether in an app or in the system, is not converted to Dalvik bytecode. Android has no built-in support for Python code.

Comment: Can you point me to any online documents describing exactly how c/c++ codes get executed on the Android OS?

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/getting-started-with-c-and-android-native-activities-2213b402ffff

Comment: You are welcome to read more about [the NDK for using C/C++ in apps](https://developer.android.com/ndk) and https://source.android.com for more about the Android OS (e.g., details of [the vendor NDK](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk)). Books on Android internals, such as [this](https://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Android-Porting-Extending-Customizing/dp/1449308295) and [this](https://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Programming-Android-Bringing-Scratch/dp/0134030001), are also available.

Comment: User-mode code doesn't "run" on a kernel. It runs on a CPU, making calls *to* privileged code within a kernel whenever certain services (such as I/O, allocation of memory pages, etc).

Comment: In Oded Radi's link, it says "Android uses a process called Zygote, to accelerate the process of launching an application or service inside the Android Runtime. This applies to every user-facing process in Android, so the first chance your app will get to run code will actually be inside a managed VM. The managed code then must load a shared library file with your logic in it, which is handled for you if you use a native activity." Is this correct? Is there a way to start a process without going through the VM?

Comment: your last comment is really your Q (isn't it?). That should have been the main thrust of your original post. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Android (native) libraries, such as OpenSSl, are run as native code, not bytecode.

Android runs C++ as native code, not bytecode.

Android runs Python through the Python interpreter, which is (by convention) usually C. However, Python can be implemented in Java; see [Jython](https://www.jython.org/).